# Best way in Pytorch to upsample a Tensor and transform it to rgb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorboard, pytorch

For a nice output in Tensorboard I want to show a batch of input images, corresponding target masks and output masks in a grid.
Input images have different size then the masks. Furthermore the images are obviously RGB.
From a batch of e.g. 32 or 64 I only want to show the first 4 images.

After some fiddling around I came up with the following example code. Good thing: It works.
But I am really not sure if I missed something in Pytorch. It just looks much longer then I expected. Especially the upsampling and transformation to RGB seems wild. But the other transformations I found would not work for a whole batch.

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as FN
import torchvision.utils as vutils
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
import time
batch = 32
i_size = 192
o_size = 112
nr_imgs = 4

# Tensorboard init
writer = SummaryWriter('runs/' + time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'))

input_image=Variable(torch.rand(batch,3,i_size,i_size))
target_mask=Variable(torch.rand(batch,o_size,o_size))
output_mask=Variable(torch.rand(batch,o_size,o_size))

# upsample target_mask, add dim to have gray2rgb
tm = FN.upsample(target_mask[:nr_imgs,None], size=[i_size, i_size], mode='bilinear')
tm = torch.cat( (tm,tm,tm), dim=1)  # grayscale plane to rgb

# upsample target_mask, add dim to have gray2rgb
om = FN.upsample(output_mask[:nr_imgs,None], size=[i_size, i_size], mode='bilinear')
om = torch.cat( (om,om,om), dim=1)  # grayscale plane to rgb

# add up all images and make grid
imgs = torch.cat( ( input_image[:nr_imgs].data, tm.data, om.data ) )
x = vutils.make_grid(imgs, nrow=nr_imgs, normalize=True, scale_each=True)

# Tensorboard img output
writer.add_image('Image', x, 0)
```

**EDIT**: Found [this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/157) on Pytorchs Issues list. Its about `Batch support for Transform`. Seems there are no plans to add batch transforms in the future. So my current code might be the best solution for the time being, anyway?

Comment: *always* add the generic python tag

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can just convert your Tensors to the numpy array (.data.cpu().numpy() ) and use opencv to do upsampling? OpenCV implementation should be quite fast.

Comment: I am working with OpenCV for the retrieval of the data. So that would be a easy move. I thought it might not be worth trying because I would have to convert back and forth and break up the batch to resize each image individually. But while thinking about it... I could change the view and resize all at once... So, probably worth a try after all! Thank you!